# Create a cloned div that works separately in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in my page which contains a table with inputs (with ids), I have some conditions and functions on the inputs written in the Javascript code. What I'm trying to do is to make a button (add new) that clones exactly the same div in the page but with same conditions and functions on the new elements and the submit button to work for each separately.

I tried this :

```
$('#button-add').bind({  
    click: function()
    {
        $("#repeat").clone().appendTo("#add");
    }                
});
```

the problem is that I get the same appearance for the div but the functions are not working (because the inputs have the same id) and i cannot submit only that block (new div).

Is there a simpler way to achieve that?

Comment: use classes instead of id's and then look into `delegated` events http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ as you are adding elements dynamically, you will have to listen to events bubbling up from those new elements to an element that has existed from the beginning such as `body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if you ignore making clones.
The way of doing it using a dynamic id.

Say if appending div with different id for every element using random function in javascript.

```
   $('#add-item').on('click', function (e) {
                        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
                        var numtd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50000) + 10000;

                        $('<tr id="trowdynamic_' + num + '">' +
                            '<td>' +
                                '<div class="input-group">' +
                                '<input type="hidden" id="selected_item_' + numtd + '" name="selected_name" />' +
                                    '<input type="text" name="Inv_Itemsdetail" value="" class="Itemsdetail-typeahead_' + numtd + ' input-search" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" />' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" id="Inv_Itemsdetail_' + numtd + '" class="auto-complete" name="Itemxx[]" />' +
                                    '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                                        '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#cardCode05"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>' +

                                    '</span>' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</td>' +'</tr>').appendTo('#yourcontainer_id');
});
```

Now using jQuery call for same id elements- 
Now **Note** this way I have every element starting with same `id` name plus a random number.

```
$('input[id^="selected_item_"]')
```

Comment: is there a way to select all the ids that begin with an id (indifferent what random number is after the id) because i have javascript functions that should be applied to the new generated elements in the new div . how can i select them if the ids are generated with random number after ?

Comment: @oday, I mentioned the same in last line. Ids are coming randomly

Comment: yes ,Thanks !
i used your solution then i modified the functions to accept parameters with new genereated ids .

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to duplicate the div, you should not use IDs, because their uniqueness would be compromised. But you can use css class names (`$('.className')`) or custom data attributes (`$('[data-my-id=xxx]')`) to address your inputs because they do not need to be unique.

Second, you need to clone your div so that the events attached to your inputs are cloned as well. Check out the jQuery doc for `.clone([withDataAndEvents] [,deepWithDataAndEvents])` (http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: the problem is that i have inputs in my div that depend on each other . if i make a class then when user selects something in the input in the first div it will change the values in the second div two wich i don't want to happen .
i want each new div to work somehow seperately as an individual page.

Comment: You can set a new ID for each main div and then address the input within that div: $('#mainDiv_1 .someInputClassName').

Comment: Or, within the event handlers of your inputs, search only the parent main div for the other inputs: $(this).closest('.mainDivClass').find('.someInputClass')

Answer (score 0):

Since the new div is created in new space ie, in `#add`, select the new div as

```
#add #repeat
{

}   //  in css
```

in `jquery` use `next or siblings or children` etc to select the new `div`

**For example**

see the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Le86j572/)